# Why does script fail to generate Schema for avro files

Tags: python, schema, avro, python-module

I installed avro modules in python by running "pip install avro" but looks like the module is not getting recognized. I ran the below code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(open('C:\\Users\\rgopi\\Downloads\\userdata1.avro.avro',"rb"),avro.io.DatumReader())
schema = reader.meta
print(schema)
```

it says "avro" : Unknown Word in Visual Studio Code. I nevertheless ran the code and it gives the below error:

*> File "d:/Junk/test.py", line 1, in

> ```
> import avro.schema   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\avro\schema.py", line 383
> except Exception, e:
>                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had installed [Python 2](https://pypi.org/project/avro/) version of avro module. I uninstalled and installed the [Python 3](https://pypi.org/project/avro-python3/) version and had to reboot it few times for it to take effect.

> import avro from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
>   from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
>
> reader =
>   avro.datafile.DataFileReader(open('C:\DataEngineering\Python\Scripts\twitter.avro',"rb"),avro.io.DatumReader())
>   schema = reader.meta print(schema)